# How can I test a client-side redirect to a 3rd party site with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, redirect, cypress

Cypress offers a simple way to test for server-side redirects using [request](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Syntax):

```
cy.request({
  url: `/dashboard/`,
  followRedirect: false, // turn off following redirects
}).then((resp) => {
  expect(resp.redirectedToUrl).to.eq('http://example.com/session/new')
})
```

However this doesn't work for client-side redirects because the page is loaded successfully before the redirect happens, meaning the response is for the page, not for the redirect.

**How can I test a client-side redirect?**

I need a way of catching the redirect and verifying that:

- it occurred
- was to the correct URL.

Note:

- I don't want to follow the redirect away from the app that is being tested. I'm not testing the whole auth flow. I just need to know there was a redirect.
- I can't change this auth flow. The redirect is unavoidable.
- The redirect happens during initialisation, not as a result of any user interaction.
- The redirect uses: `window.location.href = url`
- See my answer below for an attempt at resolving this.

Comment: Is the redirect to another page on your website?

Comment: @myjobistobehappy No.  'How can I test a client-side redirect to a 3rd party site with Cypress?'

Comment: I think I found a solution for client side. I will make it an answer in a little.

Answer (score 2):

Update: **This isn't solid**. I've just done some refactoring and it seems that even this solution is flawed. It is possible for the redirect to happen in between cypress visiting the page and triggering the `cy.wait` so the test ends up waiting for something that has already happened. The below might still work for you depending on when your redirect is triggered, but *if it's triggered on initialisation, it appears this will not work*.

Not really loving this solution as the redirect still happens (I haven't found a way to cancel it), but it at least tests that the redirect happens, and allows me to check the query:

```
cy.intercept({ pathname: `/sessions/new` }).as(`loginRedirect`)

cy.visit(`/dashboard/`)

cy.location().then(($location) => {
  cy.wait(`@loginRedirect`).then(($interceptor) => {
    const { query } = urlParse($interceptor.request.url)
    expect(query).to.equal(`?token=true&redirect=${$location.href}`)
  })
})
```

Note: `route2` changed to `intercept` in v6.

Comment: It would be useful to know how client-side redirection is implemented. I tried in JS with `window.location = ...` but `cy.intercept()` failed to catch it.

Comment: @eric99 yeah. I've just refactored the code and now this is no longer catching the redirect. The redirect is happening between `cy.visit()` and `cy.location()`, and Cypress doesn't appear to offer any means to guarantee that `cy.wait` is in place immediately on page load. I've updated the answer to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Gleb Bahmutov has an approach at [Deal with window.location.replace](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#deal-with-windowlocationreplace), which renames `window.location` in the source to `window.__location` which is effectively the stub.

It uses `cy.intercept()` to modify the loading page ***before*** it hits the browser, i.e before `window.location` is instantiated and becomes a totally immutable/incorruptible object.

```js
it('replaces', () => {

  cy.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
    win.__location = {                           // set up the stub
      replace: cy.stub().as('replace')
    }
  })

  cy.intercept('GET', 'index.html', (req) => {   // catch the page as it loads
    req.continue(res => {
      res.body = res.body.replaceAll(
        'window.location.replace', 'window.__location.replace')
    })
  }).as('index')

  cy.visit('index.html')
  cy.wait('@index')

  cy.contains('h1', 'First page')
  cy.get('@replace').should('have.been.calledOnceWith', 'https://www.cypress.io')
})
```

This stubs `replace`, but the same should work for the `href` setter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have found as the only was to detect a successful redirect client side if it is to a third-party website. JavaScript has a handy-dandy function called <kbd>window.open()</kbd>. There are many things that you can do with it including redirecting the webpage. This can be done by setting the target to <kbd>_self</kbd> or to <kbd>_top</kbd>. By using a while loop, you are running code as quickly as you can. Here is a rough-draft of how I would record a client-side redirect.

```js
var redirectURL = 'https://www.example.com/',
redirectWindow = window.open(redirectURL, '_top'),
redirected = false,
count = 0;

while(true) {
    if (redirectWindow.document.readyState === 'complete') {
        redirected = true;
        //Your code here. I am just logging that it is in the process of redirection.
        console.log('redirecting')
        break;
    }
    if (count > 2000) {
        redirected = false;
        break;
    }
    count++
    
}
if (redirected == false) {
    console.log('Error: Redirect Failed');
}
```