# Cypress - stall next page navigation

Tags: cypress

Assuming I know the URL of next page navigation, is there a way to prevent next action performing the navigation, regardless whether the navigation is directed by href or js? Tried `cy.intercept` doesn't work.

```
// doesn't work
cy.intercept({ hostname: 'cross.domain' }, (req) => {})
cy.contains('Next').click()
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing a bit more about your particular use case and what it is you are ultimately trying to achieve in your test?

Comment: @Kerry, as shown in code I'm trying to click an element but want to prevent page from navigating to another domain, which is prohibited by cypress.

Comment: Please see @Undistraction's question [How can I test a client-side redirect to a 3rd party site with Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65073966/how-can-i-test-a-client-side-redirect-to-a-3rd-party-site-with-cypress), useful for javascript redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JQ .attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
    cy.get(`aTagSelector`) //This part is recommended to check if you click the required button with the link to cross origin
        .should('have.attr', 'href')
        .and('include', `expectedUrl`)
    cy.get(`aTagSelector`)
        .then($aTagElement => {
            $aTagElement.attr("href", '/');
            cy.get($aTagElement)
                .click({force: true})
        })
```

Comment: You do not need `Cypress.$(aTagElement).attr()` because `aTagElement` is already a jquery object. By convention, you would prefix it with `$`, i.e `.then($aTagElement => {` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Can you explain why you replace the href value with `/`?

Comment: `/` opens the same page you are in. You can replace it with any url that you wish to be there.

Comment: What if navigation is not triggered by clicking href-based <a>?

Comment: @abbr That would be weird, but in that case I would look tru the code to see how is triggered and a property it is bound to. When you find that property you can use JQ `.removeAttr` to remove it: https://api.jquery.com/removeattr/

`Href` can be attached to most elements in reality, but I had never seen a code to redirect without using it.

Comment: @RosenMihaylov, I would say non-href-based navigation is more popular, for example using location.href, window.open(), window.replace().

Comment: @abbr Sorry can not help with that.